# Using Ajax to load more posts | Help me change the wording on my button to notify the user

Tags: wp-query, filters, ajax

I am having  bit of a brain melt situation trying to carry across a style of code I used on a previous website where I would change the wording on the button the user clicks to load more. I have created a working example on a filter button but can't seem to see how I can apply this to my load more button.

Currently the user will click load more, wait 5 seconds, then the new content will append to the old.

I wish for them to click the load more, the wording will change to loading, then when the content loads the wording will revert to load more.

Here is an example I have **working (don't amend this code)** on some filters...

```
jQuery(function(n) {
    n("#advanced-filterform").submit(function() {
        var e = n("#advanced-filterform");
        return n.ajax({
            url: e.attr("action"),
            data: e.serialize(),
            type: e.attr("method"),
            beforeSend: function(t) {
                e.find("button").text("Applying Filters...")
            },
            success: function(t) {
                e.find("button").text("Apply filters"), n("#response").html(t)
            }
        }), !1
    })
})
```

I wish to use a similar technique to this block of code **(edit this block of code)**:

```
var ajaxurl = "<?php echo admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php' ); ?>";
var page = 2;
jQuery(function($) {
    $('#load-more').click(function() {
        var data = {
            'action': 'load_posts_by_ajax',
            'page': page,
            'security': '<?php echo wp_create_nonce("load_more_posts"); ?>'
        };

        $.post(ajaxurl, data, function(response) {
            if(response != '') {
                $('.testimonials').append(response);
                page++;
            } else {
                $('.load-more-posts').hide();
            }
        });
    });
});
```

I am fairly new to the wonders of Ajax so would appreciate any commentary you can provide while you answer!

Big thanks to any contributors, Jason.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first block you provided can be sufficiently updated to be used with your code but see my example below:

Start of by setting up your WordPress function to load your scripts (inside functions.php) and set the global ajax script variable to use later. I am breaking it down into sections since this would the correct way of doing it:

```
function js_enqueue_scripts() {
    wp_enqueue_script("my-ajax-handle", get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . "/assets/js/ajax.js", array('jquery'));
    //the_ajax_script will use to print admin-ajaxurl in custom ajax.js
    wp_localize_script('my-ajax-handle', 'the_ajax_script', array(
        'ajaxurl' => admin_url('admin-ajax.php'), '_nonce' => wp_create_nonce('my-ajax-handle-nonce')
    ));
}

add_action("wp_enqueue_scripts", "js_enqueue_scripts");
```

After that you can add the following to functions.php, this will be used for frontend ajax requests. `nopriv` isnt needed for admin requests.

```
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_load_more_post_ajax', 'load_more_post_ajax');
add_action('wp_ajax_load_more_post_ajax', 'load_more_post_ajax');
```

The above part is the unique identifier for your ajax function, and where the data must be sent to get processed and return the response from.

Next lets build the php function to process the request we just asked for:

```
    /**
     * Load more posts using ajax.
     */
    function load_more_post_ajax() {

        if (wp_verify_nonce($_REQUEST['security'], 'my-ajax-handle-nonce') === false) {
            wp_send_json_error();
            wp_die('Invalid Request!');
        }

        $ppp = $_POST['ppp'] ?? 1;
        $page = $_POST['pageNumber'] ?? 0;

        $loop = new \WP_Query([
            'suppress_filters' => true, 'post_type' => 'post', 'posts_per_page' => $ppp, 'paged' => $page,
        ]);

        if ($loop->have_posts()) {
            while ($loop->have_posts()) : $loop->the_post();
                echo "<div><h1>' . get_the_title() . '</h1>' . get_the_content() . '</div>";
            endwhile;
        }
        wp_reset_postdata();
        wp_die(); // This must always be here, this will close to process.
    }
```

And lastly we will create the JQuery in our new file `ajax.js`:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function () {
    jQuery('#load-more').on('click', function () { //Use on operator for dom loading ease
        var $this = jQuery(this); // This is the button object
        var data = {}; // Create an Object to add variables to later if we change them
        data.action = 'load_more_post_ajax'; // Refer to action
        data.page = 2; //Add whatever else you want
        data.security = the_ajax_script._nonce;

        $this.html('Loading...'); // Change the wording on click.

        jQuery.ajax({
            url: the_ajax_script.ajaxurl,
            type: 'post',
            data: data,
            success: function (response) {
                $this.html('Load More'); // Change the wording back on success.
                if (response !== '') {
                    $('.testimonials').append(response);
                    page++;
                } else {
                    $('.load-more-posts').hide();
                }
            },
            error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                $loader.html(jqXHR + " :: " + textStatus + " :: " + errorThrown);
            }
        });
    });
});
```

you can play around with these options, the possibilities are endless.

Comment: Thanks for contributing, I didn't need as full of an answer but this would be a good resource for anyone wanting to copy the code to their own examples. So thanks... I have now got a working solution. Please upvote my question if you enjoyed answering. I will accept yours now as you have highlighted in depth how to successfully Ajax'ify posts into the page.